# How to add UTF-8 encoding in POST request

Tags: curl, post

I have following POST request:

```
curl --request POST \
 --url http://<myurl> \
 --header 'content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8' \
 --data '{
 "message": "Hebräisch?"
}'
```

I have to choose UTF-8 charset to encode the message in a proper way, for example 'hebräisch'.

I found several posts asking the same and it seems to add charset into the content-type solved their problem, but I get following error from the server:

```
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>
```

and suggestions how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You have no problem in your request. It is working fine on client side. It depends of the server you are posting to how to handle it. I tried it with Postman Echo service and it seems to be perfectly fine:

```sh
curl --request POST --url https://postman-echo.com/post --header 'content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8'  --data '{ "message": "Hebräisch?" }' | jq
```

See [Postman echo](https://postman-echo.com/) testing tool.

NB. I used `jq` to pretty-print server output, just skip it if you don't have it)